# How to use a cluster socket.io Node.js?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, cluster-computing

I currently use socket.io-redis workers to communicate and web clients. As I understand it, this leads to that that each message is duplicated in each worker. There are less expensive ways of sharing customers and workers? It is possible duplicate socket.io session on all the worker?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps,

Have you tried using `pm2` it is very easy to use, just do a `pm2 start app.js -i 0`, this will automatically cluster your application sharing a single TCP socket.

just follow [this](https://keymetrics.io/2015/03/26/pm2-clustering-made-easy/) to use and install pm2.

:)

Comment: This won't help when it comes to sockets: instead try https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session